# How to allow Urql (typescript) to accept Vue reactive variables for queries created with graphql-codegen

Tags: typescript, vue.js, graphql, graphql-codegen, urql

I'm building a Vue project with urql and graphql-codegen.

Urql has the ability to take Vue reactive variables when using `useQuery()` to enable useQuery to be reactive and update when the variables do.

But graphql-codegen is creating the type for the variables parameter to require scalars (ex. string) and so typescript is throwing an error when I try to use (for ex.) a Ref instead.

This is my codegen.ts:

```
import type { CodegenConfig } from '@graphql-codegen/cli';

const config: CodegenConfig = {
  schema: 'http://localhost:5001/graphql',
  documents: ['src/**/*.vue', 'src/**/*.ts'],
  ignoreNoDocuments: true, // for better experience with the watcher
  generates: {
    './src/gql/': {
      preset: 'client',
      config: {
        useTypeImports: true,
        scalars: {
          CustomDate: 'string',
          ObjectID: 'string',
        },
            },
      plugins: [],
    },
  },
};

export default config;
```

A sample variable type that's created looks like:

```
export type Scalars = {
  String: string;
  ObjectID: string;
};

export type GetItemQueryVariables = Exact<{
  _id: Scalars['ObjectID'];
}>;
```

And then a sample call might be:

```
const id = ref('123');

const queryResult = useQuery({
  query: queryGQL, // which is the graphql for the get item query
  variables: { _id: id }, // this line complains that type Ref<string is not assignable to type string
});
```

I can cast queryGQL to be something more generic so that it will take any variables, but that defeats the point.

Is there a setting on graphql-codegen to fix this? Or alternately, some way I could automatically patch the generated typescript definitions to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `reactive` to convert refs to properties:

```
let r = ref(123)    // Ref<number>
let a = { r }       // { r: Ref<number> }
let b = reactive(a) // { r: number }
```

Example:

```
const { data } = useQuery({
  query,
  variables: reactive({
    orderBy: ArticlesOrderBy.ViewedAt,
    order: Order.Desc,
    first: 2,
    after  // Ref<string>
  })
})
```

Comment: smartest way to solve this ever. as reactive is using proxy behind to track the change any bypass typescript checking.

Answer (score 1):

*I had the same issue. I'm using `@graphql-codegen` and urql for the first time. If anyone knows a better solution, let me know.*

#### Configuration

I followed [the official documentation](https://the-guild.dev/graphql/codegen/docs/guides/react-vue) from the `codegen` website.

#### The problem

##### URQL

The `urql` [allows us to pass](https://github.com/urql-graphql/urql/blob/main/packages/vue-urql/src/useQuery.ts#L24) ref objects as variables. It works great, especially if you write conditional queries. You can pause the query and pass in `ref` variable.

```js
const exampleQuery = useQuery({
  query: GqlQueryString,
  variables: {
    someVariable, // <- it's a reference
  },
  pause: isQueryPaused,
});
```

##### Codegen

When codegen generates types, it makes variables of a simple type. So, in the code, you will see a type error since variable can not be of type `Ref<...>`.

#### The solution

After Googling, I couldn't find any solution quickly. Documentation of `codegen` is pure and doesn't have any good examples for this case.

We need to set [scalars](https://the-guild.dev/graphql/codegen/plugins/typescript/typescript#scalars) property so it accepts both `Ref` and type.

```json
config: {
  useTypeImports: true,
  scalars: {
    String: {
      input: "string | Ref<string | undefined>",
      output: "string",
    },
    Boolean: {
      input: "boolean | Ref<boolean | undefined>",
      output: "boolean",
    },
    Int: {
      input: "number | Ref<number | undefined>",
      output: "number",
    },
    Float: {
      input: "number | Ref<number | undefined>",
      output: "number",
    },
  },
},
```

But having set that will not work. Because `Ref` is not imported in the generated file.

To import the required type, I had to write a simple plugin:

```js
// codegen-import-plugin.cjs
module.exports = {
  plugin(schema, documents, config) {
    return {
      prepend: config.imports,
      content: "",
    };
  },
  validate(schema, documents, config) {
    if (!Array.isArray(config.imports) || config.imports.length === 0) {
      throw new Error("codegen-import-plugin requires imports to be set");
    }
  },
};
```

Add the plugin to the config:

```json
plugins: [
  {
    "codegen-import-plugin.cjs": {
      imports: ["import type { Ref } from 'vue';"],
    },
  },
],
```

As a result we'll have this content in generated file:

```js
import type { Ref } from 'vue';
import type { TypedDocumentNode as DocumentNode } from '@graphql-typed-document-node/core';
export type Maybe<T> = T | null;
export type InputMaybe<T> = Maybe<T>;
export type Exact<T extends { [key: string]: unknown }> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] };
export type MakeOptional<T, K extends keyof T> = Omit<T, K> & { [SubKey in K]?: Maybe<T[SubKey]> };
export type MakeMaybe<T, K extends keyof T> = Omit<T, K> & { [SubKey in K]: Maybe<T[SubKey]> };
export type MakeEmpty<T extends { [key: string]: unknown }, K extends keyof T> = { [_ in K]?: never };
export type Incremental<T> = T | { [P in keyof T]?: P extends ' $fragmentName' | '__typename' ? T[P] : never };
/** All built-in and custom scalars, mapped to their actual values */
export type Scalars = {
  ID: { input: string; output: string; }
  String: { input: string | Ref<string | undefined>; output: string; }
  Boolean: { input: boolean | Ref<boolean | undefined>; output: boolean; }
  Int: { input: number | Ref<number | undefined>; output: number; }
  Float: { input: number; output: number; }
};
```

---

### Update #1

After talking with Google's Bard, I found that it's possible to define custom scalars. There's [a docs page](https://the-guild.dev/graphql/tools/docs/scalars) describing it. But I don't like this approach, because I need to add new scalars to each query. Also, Ref's are not related to the query itself, it's related to the urlq and `useQuery` function types.

### Update #2

It's magic  After cleaning up my deps, I noticed `useQuery`  works as expected. But `useMutation` still not using `MaybeRef$1` type from urql.

```json
# package.json
...
"dependencies": {
    "@urql/vue": "^1.1.2",
    "graphql": "^16.8.1",
    "vue": "^3.3.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@graphql-codegen/cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@graphql-codegen/client-preset": "^4.1.0",
    "@parcel/watcher": "^2.3.0",
    "@types/node": "^20.6.1",
    "@unplugin-vue-ce/sub-style": "^1.0.0-beta.16",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.2.3",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.15",
    "concurrently": "^8.2.1",
    "postcss": "^8.4.29",
    "rollup-plugin-visualizer": "^5.9.2",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.3",
    "typescript": "^5.0.2",
    "vite": "^4.4.5",
    "vite-plugin-html": "^3.2.0",
    "vite-svg-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "vue-tsc": "^1.8.5"
  }
...
```

```js
# codegen.ts
import type { CodegenConfig } from "@graphql-codegen/cli";
import { loadEnv } from "vite";

const env = loadEnv("", process.cwd());

// Documentation - https://the-guild.dev/graphql/codegen/docs/guides/react-vue
const config: CodegenConfig = {
  overwrite: true,
  schema: [
    `...path to the schema`,
  ],
  documents: ["src/**/*.vue", "src/api/graphql/**/*.ts"],
  ignoreNoDocuments: true,
  generates: {
    "./src/generated/gql/": {
      preset: "client",
      config: {
        useTypeImports: true,
      },
      plugins: [],
    },
  },
};

export default config;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another 2 problems that i found in generated file.

1. wrong ->`import * as Urql from 'urql';`
   correct -> `import * as Urql from '@urql/vue';`
2. Queries has problem with types, after generation for example

```
export function useFindUserByUrlQuery(options: Omit<Urql.UseQueryArgs<FindUserByUrlQueryVariables>, 'query'>) {
     return Urql.useQuery<FindUserByUrlQuery, FindUserByUrlQueryVariables>({ query: FindUserByUrlDocument, ...options });
}
```

it will give error query-options type

correct should be:

```
export function useFindUserByUrlQuery(options: Omit<Urql.UseQueryArgs<FindUserByUrlQueryVariables>, 'query'>  & { variables: { url: string } }) {
      return Urql.useQuery<FindUserByUrlQuery, FindUserByUrlQueryVariables>({ query: FindUserByUrlDocument, ...options });
    }
```

If i am not write please comment